# HashMap - Search for Value of Object and add to list

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 classes Gym and gymMember. Currently Gym stores all gymMember in a HashMap gymMembers where String is their member ID (String).

gymMember holds the variables:

```
  this.fullName = aName;
  this.address = anAddress;
  this.area = anArea;
```

What i'd like to go is search through the the HashMap gymMembers to find out what members are in area 1 stores in variable this.area and then return the gymMember object to a new set.

So far i've got this far:

```
public void findCustomersInArea(int x)
{
    // create a list to store all Customers
List<gymMember> aMember = new ArrayList<gymMember>();

// iterate all entries in the map
for (Map.Entry<String, gymMember> a: gymMembers.entrySet())
{
    // get the customer
    gymMember newMember = a.getArea();
    if (newMember.getArea() == x) {
        // do what you need to add to a list
       newMember.add(newCustomer);
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone have ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: You should describe exactly what the problem is. Also, I highly recommend you name your classes starting with a capital letter (GymMember) as names with a small letter are for variables (gymMembers).

Comment: The problem is that the code is not compiling at the moment and i'm very unsure if this is the correct way in which to get the required result. Many thanks :)

Comment: One problem I can see is `a.getArea()`. The `Map.Entry` class has two getters: `getKey()` and `getValue()`. I think you meant `a.getValue()`. Also, once you've built your `aMember` list, you'll need to return it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
gymMember newMember = a.getValue ();
if (newMember.getArea() == x) {
    // do what you need to add to a list
   aMember.add(newMember);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While iterating through the `Map`, instead of `gymMember newMember = a.getArea();`you should be doing:

`gymMember newMember = a.getValue();`Following would be your code:

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, gymMember> a : gymMembers.entrySet()) {
        // get the customer
        gymMember newMember = a.getValue();
        if (newMember.getArea() == x) {
            // do what you need to add to a list
            aMember.add(newCustomer);//The name of your list is aMember and not newMember
        }
    }
```

since you want to check the `area` of each `gymMember` and not `area` of each `entry` in the `map`. In this case, since you are just accessing the values(i.e. `gymMember`) associated with each id, you can do:

```
    for (gymMember gymMember : gymMembers.values()) {//where your Object would be gymMember
          if (gymMember.getArea() == x) {
            aMember.add(gymMember);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That should be `for (gymMember g : gymMember.values()) { if (g.getArea...`

Comment: Yes that's correct. I just generalized it to be an Object just to indicate the concept. That's why I have commented. Editing it to be a `gymMember` as well....